Unable to Install sklearn on PyCharm (macOS) Despite Having Correct Python and pip Versions
I am trying to install sklearn on PyCharm (macOS), but I'm encountering issues even though I have the correct Python and pip versions installed.
Here are the details:
OS: macOS 11.2 Big Sur
Python Version: 3.8
pip Version: 24.3.1
PyCharm Version: 2024.3 professional edition
Steps I have taken so far:

Verified that pip is up to date (pip install --upgrade pip).
Checked that the Python interpreter in PyCharm matches my system’s Python version.
Tried installing scikit-learn both via PyCharm’s terminal and its package manager (pip install scikit-learn).
Checked for any errors in the terminal logs.

Error message I’m getting:
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.3.2.tar.gz (7.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [82 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-75.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.45.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
      Collecting Cython<3.0,>=0.29.33
        Using cached Cython-0.29.37-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
        Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2023.12.21-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.8 kB)
      Collecting scipy>=1.5.0
        Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [50 lines of output]
            The Meson build system
            Version: 1.6.1
            Source dir: /private/var/folders/54/5_0w35554ql5vmbrsf3_vpvc0000gn/T/pip-install-2w0grdxz/scipy_4f075648eff940ea86a6b4776c22b4e4
            Build dir: /private/var/folders/54/5_0w35554ql5vmbrsf3_vpvc0000gn/T/pip-install-2w0grdxz/scipy_4f075648eff940ea86a6b4776c22b4e4/.mesonpy-q_cgjrse/build
            Build type: native build
            Project name: SciPy
            Project version: 1.10.1
            C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 13.0.0 "Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)")
            C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 711
            C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (clang 13.0.0 "Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)")
            C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld64 711
            Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.37)
            Host machine cpu family: aarch64
            Host machine cpu: aarch64
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: YES
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: YES
            Library m found: YES
      
            ../../meson.build:63:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['gfortran'], ['flang-new'], ['flang'], ['nvfortran'], ['pgfortran'], ['ifort'], ['ifx'], ['g95']]
            The following exception(s) were encountered:
            Running `gfortran --help` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
            Running `gfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
            Running `gfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
            Running `flang-new --help` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang-new'"
            Running `flang-new --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang-new'"
            Running `flang-new -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang-new'"
            Running `flang --help` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
            Running `flang --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
            Running `flang -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
            Running `nvfortran --help` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
            Running `nvfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
            Running `nvfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
            Running `pgfortran --help` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
            Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
            Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
            Running `ifort --help` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
            Running `ifort --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
            Running `ifort -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
            Running `ifx --help` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
            Running `ifx --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
            Running `ifx -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
            Running `g95 --help` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
            Running `g95 --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
            Running `g95 -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
      
            A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/54/5_0w35554ql5vmbrsf3_vpvc0000gn/T/pip-install-2w0grdxz/scipy_4f075648eff940ea86a6b4776c22b4e4/.mesonpy-q_cgjrse/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
            + meson setup --prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8 /private/var/folders/54/5_0w35554ql5vmbrsf3_vpvc0000gn/T/pip-install-2w0grdxz/scipy_4f075648eff940ea86a6b4776c22b4e4 /private/var/folders/54/5_0w35554ql5vmbrsf3_vpvc0000gn/T/pip-install-2w0grdxz/scipy_4f075648eff940ea86a6b4776c22b4e4/.mesonpy-q_cgjrse/build --native-file=/private/var/folders/54/5_0w35554ql5vmbrsf3_vpvc0000gn/T/pip-install-2w0grdxz/scipy_4f075648eff940ea86a6b4776c22b4e4/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed
      
      × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
      ╰─> See above for output.
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. 

I've also tried re-installing command line tools for Xcode and upgraded them, for one of the previous errors stated missing dependencies, specifically a Fortran compiler that is required for building certain packages (such as scipy, which scikit-learn depends on).
Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue? Could this be related to PyCharm’s interpreter settings, macOS environment configurations, or a dependency issue?

You should include the full error message, this is just one line, else people will not be able to help you.

Do you actually have a Fortran compiler installed? Which one specifically? Is it in your PATH? Are you able to run it from the command line? Are you able to compile a hellow world program with it?
